# How do add an OpenID service to an embedded Jetty server. Getting No IdentityService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.openid.OpenIdAuthenticator

Tags: java, jetty, openid, embedded-jetty

I am trying to add an OpenId service to an embedded Jetty Server. I followed the Jetty documentation [Here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#openid-support) and now I am getting the following error.

> No IdentityService for
> org.eclipse.jetty.security.openid.OpenIdAuthenticator

I can't seem to find a full example of setting this up in Jetty and I am not sure about how to set up an Identity Service. The following is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
if (args.length != 1) {
  System.err.println("Usage: need a relative path to the war file to execute");
  System.exit(1);
}

System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog");
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "INFO");

// Create a basic Jetty server object that will listen on port defined by
// the PORT environment variable when present, otherwise on 8080.
int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("PORT", "8080"));
Server server = new Server(port);

System.out.println("clientid = " + clientId);
System.out.println("clientSecret = " + clientSecret);

// The WebAppContext is the interface to provide configuration for a web
// application. In this example, the context path is being set to "/" so
// it is suitable for serving root context requests.
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setWar(args[0]);
ClassList classlist = ClassList.setServerDefault(server);

// Enable Annotation Scanning.
classlist.addBefore(
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

OpenIdConfiguration openIdConfig = new OpenIdConfiguration(issuer, clientId, clientSecret);
OpenIdLoginService loginService = new OpenIdLoginService(openIdConfig);
Authenticator authenticator = new OpenIdAuthenticator(openIdConfig, "/error");


SecurityHandler securityHandler = webapp.getSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
securityHandler.setIdentityService(loginService.getIdentityService());

webapp.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
// Set the the WebAppContext as the ContextHandler for the server.
server.setHandler(webapp);

// Start the server! By using the server.join() the server thread will
// join with the current thread. See
// "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()"
// for more details.
server.start();
server.join();
```

}

If anyone has any guidance I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: When does that error occur - i.e. at which line? Try using a debugging tool to see your instance properties. Have you tried setting the IdentityService on the SecurityHandler prior to setting the Authenticator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the identity service to be null because no `IdentityService` has been set on the `OpenIdLoginService`.

You can set the `IdentityService` explicitly with:

```java
SecurityHandler securityHandler = webapp.getSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
securityHandler.setIdentityService(new DefaultIdentityService());
```

Alternatively if you define a realm name without setting an `IdentityService`, then one will automatically be created when starting.

```java
SecurityHandler securityHandler = webapp.getSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setRealmName(issuer);
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
```

Comment: That did it. I added securityHandler.setRealmName(issuer); line and now it isn't complaining about an IdentityService. Thank you so much for responding. I have been fighting this for a very long time.